# Google Map Api - Change color of the markers

Tags: api, google-maps-markers

I use the googleMapAPI.class.php for a website.

My adresses are located in a database, and I see my adresses on a map without problem.

But, the marker is the famous red one, and I would like to change it!

You know if it's possible?

The code of my page is

```html
<?php
//(1) On inclut la classe de Google Maps pour générer ensuite la carte.
require('GoogleMapAPI.class.php');

//(2) On crée une nouvelle carte; Ici, notre carte sera $map.
$map = new GoogleMapAPI('map');

//(3) On ajoute la clef de Google Maps.
$map->setAPIKey('njkhjkhjkhjkhkj');
    
//(4) On ajoute les caractéristiques que l'on désire à notre carte.
/*
$map->setWidth("800px");
$map->setHeight("500px");
$map->setCenterCoords ('2', '48');
$map->setZoomLevel (5);
$map->disableDirections();
*/

$map->SetWidth ('100%');
$map->SetHeight ('500px');
$map->setCenterCoords ('2', '48');
$map->setZoomLevel (5);
$map->setControlSize('small');
$map->disableTypeControls();
$map->setMapType('map');
$map->disableDirections();


// Connexion à la base de données
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8889;dbname=DB;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
 

$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM Adresses");

 while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
 
{
$map->addMarkerByCoords(htmlspecialchars($donnees['GPSE']), $donnees['GPSN'] , "Maison", $donnees['Nom'], "<Appart>"); 

}
$reponse->closeCursor();
```

And for the api, I share the link because it's too long!
[Google Map Api class.php](http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/GoogleMapAPI/)

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you add your icon, provide the URL to the icon you wish to use as the next parameter:

```
$map->addMarkerByCoords(
  htmlspecialchars($donnees['GPSE']),
  $donnees['GPSN'] ,
  "Maison",
  $donnees['Nom'],
  "<Appart>",
  "http://path/to/your/icon.gif"
);
```